# IOS Animations with three images using

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimage

I have an image of a panther with its eyes open, and two PNG with transparent backgrounds of a the same panthers eyes mid closed and closed. I am trying to animate this to appear like he's blinking every 30 or so seconds but I can't figure out how to make it work properly, or even repeat after 30 seconds once the animation is done.

Here is my code so far:

```
//This is the panther image, eyes are open
UIImageView *PantherOpenImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Screen_01_PantherEyes_Open"]];
PantherOpenImageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:PantherOpenImageView];
PantherOpenImageView.layer.zPosition = 1;

//This is the png image of the panthers eyes, eyes mid-closed
UIImageView *PantherMidImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Screen_01_PantherEyes_Mid"]];
PantherMidImageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:PantherMidImageView];
PantherMidImageView.layer.zPosition = 2;
PantherMidImageView.alpha = 0; 

//This is the png image of the panthers eyes, eyes closed
UIImageView *PantherClosedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Screen_01_PantherEyes_Closed"]];
PantherClosedImageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:PantherClosedImageView];
PantherClosedImageView.layer.zPosition = 2;
PantherClosedImageView.alpha = 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
          delay:4.0f
          options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
          animations:^{
                    PantherMidImageView.alpha = 1;
                    //delay
                    PantherMidImageView.alpha = 0;
                    PantherClosedImageView.alpha = 1;
                    //delay
                    PantherClosedImageView.alpha = 0;
                 }
         completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in the `animations:^{}` block executes concurrently, so you need to define four animations with different delays. I would suggest setting the zPosition of the eyes closed layer to 3, so you can then define a "blink" method like so:

```
- (void)pantherBlink
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         PantherMidImageView.alpha = 1;
                     }
                     completion:NULL];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                          delay:0.7f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         PantherClosedImageView.alpha = 1;
                     }
                     completion:NULL];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                          delay:1.4f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         PantherClosedImageView.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:NULL];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                          delay:2.1f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         PantherMidImageView.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
}
```

You can then create a timer which calls this method every 30 seconds:

```
NSTimer blinkTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(pantherBlink)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
```

Comment: For some reason the alpha isn't changing but the animation code is being run because I put an NSLOG in it and its getting fired.

Comment: Do you mean that none of the images change? What if you do just one animation and try to fade out the open eyes image, using `PantherOpenImageView.alpha = 0.0;`?